# Pandas - Replacing values in a specific column

Tags: pandas

I am trying to replace all values in a specific column in a Dataframe if greater than 0. I tried the below but it replace all columns of that specific row.

```
df.loc[(df['count'] > 0)] = 1
```

Could anyone assist, thanks..

Answer (score 2):

You are close, need specify column in second parameter:

```
df.loc[df['count'] > 0, 'count'] = 1
```

You can also specify multiple columns:

```
df.loc[df['count'] > 0, ['count', 'another col']] = 1
```

Another solution is:

```
df['count'] = np.where(df['count'] > 0, 1, df['count'])
#alternative    
#df['count'] = df['count'].mask(df['count'] > 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

try the following sample of code; it is more felxible:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(low=-2, high=3, size=10)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['value'])
df['new_value'] = df.value.apply(lambda i : i if i < 0 else 1)
print(df)
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[(df['count'] > 0), 'count'] = 1
```

I recommand this tutorial about .loc https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvpNA7bC8cs